# How to write an Oracle stored procedure that can be used by the Telerik report wizard?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, telerik-reporting

I looked online for this information and I couldn't find too much.

How do I write a stored procedure that returns the results of a SELECT statement to a Telerik report? It is pretty simple to this with SQL Server, but I know have to use a ref cursor in Oracle.

I found an [article](http://www.pdssoftware.com/newsletter/mar07/page6.htm) on how to do it for Crystal Reports and thought it might be similar but it didn't work for me and I get the following error:

[image]

Any guidance/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding directly to the results of your stored proc, try making the call from a class that pushes the data into a Data Model. Create a method/property to expose that data and then use the telerik wizard to bind to the results of the method call using the Telerik implementation of ObjectDataSource. It looks like your problem is being caused by telerik trying to guess how to convert your data.